# Pointer wrapper so I can overload operators?

Tags: c++

I have a immutable string class which is returned by a pointer (it's allowed to be null).

I wanted to overload `ImmutableString* == const char*`. However it appears I can't because the left param is a pointer and it must be a nonpointer. The function does handle comparing null members I just can't overload it.

Whats pointer wrapper might I use so I may use so I can do the overloading I want? Preferably a standard one. I suspect I can write my own easily but my gut says boost or stl has one.

Comment: Scrap the ugly design and stay away from pointers?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I can't. I am using C and void* callbacks. I can make them references in some places but ref cannot be null

Comment: If you return an `ImmutableString*` from a function, who is responsible for destroying it?

Comment: @FredOverflow The same as WrapString. The caller... and this is always true (everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a standard wrapper for this, but it shouldn't be too hard to write one from scratch.  A very simple one would look something like this:

```
class WrappedImmutableString {
private:
    ImmutableString *value;
public:
    WrappedImmutableString(ImmutableString *value): value(value);
    char operator*() const { return value; } // dereference operator
    bool operator==(const char *other) {...}
    void delete() { delete value; }
};
```

But note that you'd need to replace "delete myImmutableString" with "myImmutableString.delete()".

That being said, I think that what you're trying to do is probably a **Bad Idea**.

Comment: What @R.MartinhoFernandes said. Also i found this code to be very bad. Theres no mention of -> and * and this isnt templated. Theres no == nor ==. Delete is wrong and i couldnt use reuse any line here except `public:`. +0. This should have been a comment. Also not a bad idea. std::strings can be compared via == which is essentially what i want but using my own lightweight class.

Comment: I would put decent odds on not even needing a wrapper -- there's a decent chance `ImmutableString` is *already* suitable for this purpose  (or is easily modified to be) and he could return functions that just return them rather than pointers to them.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... smart pointer? `std::auto_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

**But** why would you compare two pointers like that? Seems to me like the correct way to do it is to implement `ImmutableString::operator == (const char*)` and use an object instead of a pointer.

```
 ImmutableString* is = foo();
 (*is) == "whatever"
```

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated due to many semantical problems with it. It was replaced by `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `weak_ptr`. If you don't have these, try std::tr1 or tr1:: namespaces. If not even those, then use boost.

Comment: The problem with this approach is when i use find() on vector the string would not be found as it compares by ptr rather then string equality

Comment: @acidzombie24: ... which is what one should *want*. One usually should not treat "pointer to string" as if it were really "string". Making a hack so that `find` can be used that way is not worth creating a semantic nightmare everywhere else. Especially when you can just use `find_if` without any hacks. (or store values in your vector instead of pointers, if possible)